# Table doesn't format as expected

Tags: html, css

I have a table that displays as I wish, however I added a button below so the user can expand and show a secondary table. However, this second table does not display like the first one and I wanted to know why that is. The second table displays to the left with no spacing between the boxes as expected

First table (displays correctly)

```html
<div id="expenses-table">
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Supplier</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Reason</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="text"></th>
      <th><input type="text"></th>
      <th><input type="text"></th>
      <th><input type="text"></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
  <br>
  <br>
```

Second table in question, doesn't display like the first one

```css
.table,
tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table id="expand" style="display:none" class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Supplier</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Reason</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
  </tr>
</table>
</table>
</div>

<button id="expand-btn" class="button" onClick="expandTable()">Expand</button>
```

Comment: Please format the html to be easely readable, and use `td` not `th` for cells (except header cells). and in the `expandTable()` are u setting the display back to `table` or used `display: block` ?

Comment: Please update the snippet demo. You have HTML issues, which are apparent when editing. I suggest that you eliminate the JavaScript from the question and just show the troublesome HTML. We can't see it how it's set up now.  See [ask] and take the [tour] for tips.

Comment: Protip: Don't use line breaks for spacing. That's not their purpose. Use margin or padding, ideally with custom CSS classes or those from your style library.

Comment: Also no need to put 5 identical rows of inputs in a *minimal reproducible example*, and remove the pending `</table>`

Comment: clicking on expand throws an error, as there is no javascript to expand it

Comment: This should be a single snippet, more concise, not having stray tags that don't have matching open/close tags, no extra tags (<br>), and... as others have mentioned, you should correct the HTML to use TD instead of TH for actual cells. Also, you need to include the code for ExpandTable, because we can't know it's not causing the problem.

Comment: @mlibby I tried to make it all in one and it wouldn't let me post it, not sure what I was doing to it. This was the only way I tried that would let me actually post the question. I've changed TH to TD. Code for expandTable is:

function expandTable() {
    document.getElementById("expand").style.display = "block";
}

Answer (score 1):

As you're not responding to comments or developing further more your question as requested (which is exactly the opposite of what you're required to do when asking). Imma try to guess your final goal and present the following.

*Again! change the `th` tag to `td` for all table cells except the for header*

```js
function expandTable() {
  document.getElementById("expand").classList.toggle('hidden');
}
```

```css
.table,
tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="expenses-table">
  <table class="table mb-4">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Supplier</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Reason</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="text"></th>
      <th><input type="text"></th>
      <th><input type="text"></th>
      <th><input type="text"></th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody id="expand" class="hidden">
  <tr>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
    <th><input type="text"></th>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<button id="expand-btn" class="button" onClick="expandTable()">Expand</button>
```

Comment: I had other things to do as well, thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you need to wrap a table inside another table, you need to do something like this (nest a < table > inside a < table > tag):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <table>
           <tr>
              <td></td>
           </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

In addition, CSS cannot control table cell well. When content are long, table will expend by itself, like this:
[image]

[image]

Therefore, use < div > instead of < table > if you really need control the style.

Comment: If you have data that semantically fits into a table, use a table. Unless you plan on making sure your <div>s are all exactly the same as a real table from an accessibility point of view. https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/table/examples/table/